# How to stop player falling through blocks without bounce

Tags: collision-resolution, game-maker

So I have this game and I have applied gravity to it and when I load it up it just falls through the blocks and out of the screen. I have tried the bounce event but it just goes into an endless loop of bouncing.

Comment: Please provide additional information.  Are you using GM:S v1.x or v2.x?  Are you using a third-party physics library or only GM:S built-in resources? Do you have a sample of your code such that we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking for a collision with solid objects, don't use the *bounce* function, do use instead the *move to contact* function, and set the certical speed to 0. Furthermore, in the *Step Event* you may want to set gravity to `0.5` if there's no collision with solid objects below the player, and to `0` otherwise.